# Mapping doesn't work ORM

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have this example:

Log.php

```
    <?php
// src/Mailing/MailingBundle/Entity/Log.php

namespace Mailing\MailingBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="log")
*/

class Log
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
     */
    protected $action;

    public function getAction() {
        return $this->action;
    }

    public function setAction($action) {
        $this->action = $action;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $date;

    public function getDate() {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function setDate($date) {
        $this->date = $date;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="mail_id")
     * @ORM\oneToOne(targetEntity="Mail")
     */
    protected $mail;

    public function getMail() {
        return $this->mail;
    }

    public function setMail($mail) {
        $this->mail = $mail;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="template_id")
     * @ORM\oneToOne(targetEntity="Template")
     */
    protected $template;

    public function getTemplate() {
        return $this->template;
    }

    public function setTemplate($template) {
        $this->template = $template;
    }
}
```

Mail.php

```
<?php
// src/Mailing/MailingBundle/Entity/Mail.php

namespace Mailing\MailingBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="mail")
*/

class Mail
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200)
     */
    protected $address;

    /**
     * 
     * @return type
     */
    public function getAddress() {
        return $this->address;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param \Mailing\MailingBundle\Entity\Mail $surname
     */
    public function setAddress($address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * 
     * @return type
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param \Mailing\MailingBundle\Entity\Mail $surname
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200)
     */
    protected $surname;

    /**
     * 
     * @return type
     */
    public function getSurname() {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param \Mailing\MailingBundle\Entity\Mail $surname
     */
    public function setSurname($surname)
    {
        $this->surname = $surname;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    protected $subscribed;

    /**
     * 
     * @return type
     */
    public function getSubscribed() {
        return $this->subscribed;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param \Mailing\MailingBundle\Entity\Mail $subscribed
     */
    public function setSubscribed($subscribed)
    {
        $this->subscribed = $subscribed;
    }


    /**
     * @ORM\manyToMany(targetEntity="Inventory", inversedBy="articles")
     * @ORM\joinTable(
     *     name="mail_inventory",
     *     joinColumns={
     *         @ORM\joinColumn(name="mail_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *     },
     *     inverseJoinColumns={
     *         @ORM\joinColumn(name="iventory_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *     }
     * )
     */
    protected $inventories;

    /**
     * @return DoctrineCommonCollectionsCollection;
     */
    public function getInventories()
    {
        return $this->inventories;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128)
     */
    protected $hash;

    public function getHash() {
        return $this->hash;
    }

    public function setHash($hash) {
        $this->hash = $hash;
    }

}
```

LogController.php

```
<?php
// src/Mailing/MailingBundle/Controller/LogController.php

namespace Mailing\MailingBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class LogController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $records = $em->getRepository('MailingBundle:Log')->findAll();        
        return $this->render('MailingBundle:Log:index.html.twig', array('logs' =>$records));
    }
}
```

Template:

```
{# src/Mailing/MailingBundle/Resources/views/Log/index.html.twig #}
{% extends 'MailingBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}
    Log
{% endblock %}

{% block headline %}
    Log
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% if logs %}
    <table>
        <tr><th>Date</th><th>E-mail</th><th>Template</th></tr>
        {% for log in logs %}
                <tr><td>{{ log.date|date('H:i j.n.Y') }}</td><td>{{ log.action }}</td><td>{{ log.mail.address }}</td><td>{{ log.template.name }}</td></tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    {% else %}
        No records to show...
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

It generates this error:

`Impossible to access an attribute ("address") on a integer variable ("1") in MailingBundle:Log:index.html.twig at line 17`

This is DB Schema

```
log
id  int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
action  varchar(20) YES     NULL    
date    datetime    YES     NULL    
mail_id int(11) NO  MUL NULL    
template_id int(11) YES MUL NULL

mail
Field   Type    Null    Key     Default     Extra   
id  int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
address varchar(200)    NO      NULL    
name    varchar(200)    YES     NULL    
surname varchar(200)    YES     NULL    
subscribed  tinyint(1)  YES     1   
hash    varchar(128)    NO      NULL
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation: [doctrine doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-onetoone)

You were wrong to declare the record:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="mail_id")
 * @ORM\oneToOne(targetEntity="Mail")
 */
protected $mail;
```

instead must be:

```
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Mail")
 * @JoinColumn(name="mail_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 protected $mail;
```

The same thing for `$template`.

**EDIT:**

If you can not make it work you can try the bidirectional association: [onetoone bidirectional](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional)

Log.php

```
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Mail", inversedBy="log")
 * @JoinColumn(name="mail_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 protected $mail;
```

Mail.php

```
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Log", mappedBy="mail")
 **/
private $log;
```

Comment: It is generating by default with this annotation. I tried to add it and it is the same. Thank you.

Comment: You've updated the database and deleted the cache?
This is the statement of the documentation, and it works for me.
If you can not make it work, you can try two-way binding, see my update.

Comment: I really dont know why it doesnt work :( I clear up cache, but no success. I dont want to have bidirectional. It doesn make no sense.

Comment: I say this just to be safe .. but you have copied and pasted the correct example that I posted?
Why you declared `@ORM\oneToOne` but must be `@ORM\OneToOne`. I would not like that there are only problems syntax!

Comment: WHen I change to OneToOne I get this error:
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@OneToOne" in property Mailing\MailingBundle\Entity\Log::$mail was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

Comment: It has to be `@ORM\OneToOne` not `@OneToOne`!
Check if there is `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: I am sorry I have to add ORM\ Now, thos works. Thank you very much I am stupid...

Comment: No problem! It happens when you're too much time watching the same code! ;)